# Google maps animation issue when multiple click on marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, animation

I have a very simple Google Map API that I am animating the markers when clicking on an external button.  This works perfectly.  However I wanted to **stop all animation** when I click on the next marker and then re-initialize the marker I clicked on --- Otherwise the "other" markers remain animated.

Basically I have a button for each marker:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary name-btn" onclick=scrollToMarker('2')>"</button>
```

When I enter the `scrollToMarker()` function, I attempt to stop all animations by rolling through all markers, setting animation to off, and then initialize animation on the marker indicated in the function call (in this case marker 2).

```
function scrollToMarker(index) {
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        markers[i].setAnimation(null);
        console.log('Marker ' + i + ' stopped');
    }

    map.panTo(markers[index].getPosition());
    markers[index].setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
    console.log('Marker ' + index + ' animated');
}
```

This all works great.  Here's where the issue is.  If I click on marker 2 a second time, (while animated) it bounces one time and then animation ceases. I was looking to see if this was a synchronicity issue, but my console log indicates that it is happening in the correct order IE

```
Marker 0 stopped
Marker 1 stopped
Marker 2 stopped
Marker 3 stopped
Marker 4 stopped
Marker 2 animated  <--  Indicating that it animated AFTER the others had been stopped
```

What would cause this marker to bounce once and then stop animation ONLY if clicked multiple (2 or more) times in a row (without clicking to another marker) ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an exact answer as to why this behavior exists, but it seems to be an issue within the maps API. To resolve the issue you can try wrapping the set setAnimation in a timeout like this:

```
function scrollToMarker(index) {
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        markers[i].setAnimation(null);
        console.log('Marker ' + i + ' stopped');
    }

    setTimeout(function() {
        map.panTo(markers[index].getPosition());
        markers[index].setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
        console.log('Marker ' + index + ' animated');
    });
}
```